# angular service not stop when I move page

Tags: angularjs, memory, service

I made angular service that works recursively itself.

I expect When I call the service and move to another page, It supposed to stop the service.

BUT It keep working until the service is done its work.

I think It's because of remaining on memory, it's alive.

How should I make the service work only on a single page? or how to completely remove the service from memory once moving another page?

Comment: May be a blunder. But why you refer that script file in your new page?

Comment: because of tons of page and controllers, I needed to use lazy loading and service to not make whole code in single page.